# Signing out from TFS and sign in with new credentials

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

Im working VS 2015 and TFS 2015. By mistake I logged into TFS with a different credentials which is some what unused one. But after that TFS connection manager not asking for new credentials and its using the details I entered first.

So based on some search I found we can remove that from **Credential manager** but unfortunately its not showing anything related to TFS.

Also based on another solution I opened integrated web broswer window  in VS and opened the TFS page. There its login default with my first details. So when ever I click on the name, the broswer freezes and VS crashes and restarts.

So I really got stucked and having no idea what to do. So what can I do to signoff the first credentials from TFS

Comment: Go to team Explorer - Connect - Servers.. - Remove existing server and add new with new credentials.. Have you tried this?

Comment: Yes.. I tried it. When we try adding an old one which was before it wont ask us for credentials.. Thats the tough side.

Comment: Oh cool. I'm out of options, check this if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20538441/run-as-different-user-visual-studio-cannot-clear-cached-tfs-credentials

Comment: Try deleting all VS app data. I would start with deleting %appdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<<Version>>\Team Explorer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's strange that only ***local*** windows account can show the TFS credential under the **Credential manager**.
So if you are using local user, you can remove the credentials from Credential manager:
Go to **Control Panel** > **User Accounts** > **Manage Your Credentials** > select your Team foundation Server and choose remove.

If you are using ***domain*** user it shows nothing TFS related credentials under **Credential manager**, in this case please try to run Visual Studio using this command instead:

```
runas /netonly /user:<account> devenv.exe
```

This should have the Visual Studio to run with another Windows user so it can connect to remote TFS with different credentials.
[image]

Comment: Love you man.. Love you.. Its been 3rd day Ive got stucked with it... Give me your address so that I can send chocolates..
Boss one more question.. How can we make it run always with that user.. Or do we need to run it with command prompt only??

Comment: It's my pleasure, glad to hear that the workaround helps

Comment: As far as i know we can only run it with command prompt. BTW another way is click **Run as different user** in **devenv.exe** context menu, but I can't find this option in the context menu,you can try this in you side.   I tried to remember the credentials but it does not work. We have to remove previous credentials first If you want to make it run always with that user. For Domain Account I don't know how the credentials to be stored, if we can find the stored credentials then remove them maybe it works.

Comment: Yea.. Anyway that was a million dollar answer for me.. I am ready to run using command prompt.. No issues since the actual problem solved. Yea ours is a domain account. So local credential manager doesnt stores anything related with TFS

Comment: Pressing Windows key + R and type netplwiz take you straight to user accounts and manage passwords

Answer (score 3):

Go to Credential Manager

Delete the TFS related credentials

Then in Credential Manager add Generic Credentials for the TFS account. **This would overwrite the cached credentials.**

I tried so many different things and this is what worked for me. Hopefully it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using VS 2017. What worked for me is to comment out (or delete) the XML settings inside this file:

C:\Users\*yourusername*\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_9d86f7c0\Team Explorer\TeamExplorer.config