# Visual Studio 2015/7 Reset to as if i just installed it

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tfs, visual-studio-2017, checkin-policy

I am working with VS2015/2017 Enterprise, and having an on premise TFS.
As part of our check-in policy, we require to insert Code reviewer.
Yet it appears that on some machines this Window is gone "Notes.

Ive logged in to the a machine (windows 10) with similar issue, opened VS2015, and since it was my first login, Windows has created profile, and VS was opened also for the first time.
Ive checked the Check-in policy and was prompted to insert Code reviewer in the "Notes" section.

Thus is my question, how to reset the VS to be as OOB?
** Ive tried cleaning cache, restarting, in VS options reset setting to General, it's all no good.

What am i missing?

TY :}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you didn't connect to TFS with the correct credential.

Please try below items to narrow down the issue:

- Remove the TFS related credentials from **Credential Manager**
- In Credential Manager add the new updated **Generic Credentials** for the TFS account.
  Generally, this would overwrite the cached credentials.
- Close all Visual Studio instances, delete
  `%LOCALAPPDATA%\.IdentityService` as you did.
- Clear TFS caches `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\7.0\Cache`
- Clear all the browser caches especially for the stored password
- Restart Visual Studio  > Team Explorer > Manage Connections to check
  if the `Enter credential dialog` popup. Just try this several times.
  Based on my test the dialog will popup the first time, but if you cancel
  it, then you have to restart VS to popup it again.
- Run Visual Studio as another user:

  `cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE`

  `runas /netonly /user:<account> devenv.exe`

  Enter the user possword, then `Team Explorer` > `Manage Connections`
- Run "`devenv /resetuserdata`" command in the VS Developer Command Prompt as an Administrator to reset the data.

Refer to this related thread for more information : [How to use different accounts to connect to TFS in VS 2015 and VS 2017?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50251775/how-to-use-different-accounts-to-connect-to-tfs-in-vs-2015-and-vs-2017?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking time to reply!
Ive tried that on a test machine, seems to be ok, ill do the same on the problematic, i think thats gonna solve it.

Thank you one more time !